# Laravel: How can i pass data from controller to blade using yajra/laravel-datatables

Tags: php, datatable, pagination, laravel-5.5, yajra-datatable

I am using **yajra/laravel-datatables.** It's successfully installed. Now, how can i pass data **Laravel Controller** to **blade**??

```
$contacts = Contact::Where('is_deleted',0)->get();
```

This is the code. There are lots of data. For those reason, It takes lots of time to load in dataTable. I want to load and pass data to dataTable using **yajra/laravel-datatables.**

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views   ??

Answer (score 0):

There are many option which you can use

compact method

```
  $data = Contact::Where('is_deleted',0)->get();
  return view('home',compact('data'))
```

with method

```
$data = Contact::Where('is_deleted',0)->get()
        ->with('data',$data);
```

For more information, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)